# how to add initial values of radio group inside of ant form ( AntDesign Form and radio )

Tags: reactjs, antd

check it out, it is working now [ant form radio init value](https://codesandbox.io/s/ant-form-radio-inital-value-sxu9dx)

- we can use initalValues
- if we want to update when component update, we can use setFieldsValue of ant form

```
const [sampleForm] = Form.useForm();
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    // if you want to update inital value, while component is update
 sampleForm.setFieldsValue({ pregnancyStatus: false });
}, ["update inittal"]);
```

````
<Form.Item
 label={"pregnancyStatus"}
 name="pregnancyStatus"
 valuePropName="value"
// define valuePropName is what value will accept by radio group
>
 <Radio.Group>
  <Radio value={true}>Yes</Radio>
  <Radio value={false}>No</Radio>
 </Radio.Group>
</Form.Item>```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
 const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;
 const {  Col, Form, Radio, } = antd;
 const {  useState  } = React;
 
 const App = () => {
   const [value1, setValue1] = useState();
  const onChange1 = ({ target: { value } }) => {
     console.log('radio1 checked', value);
     setValue1(value);
   };
 return(
   <>
 <Col lg={12} md={12} sm={24}>
   <Form>
   <Form.Item
     label={("page.pregnancy_status")}
      name="pregnancyStatus"
      valuePropName="checked"
   >
     <Form.Item name="radio-group"  label="Radio.Group">
       <Radio.Group value={value1} onChange={onChange1}>
         <Radio value={true}>Yes</Radio>
       <Radio value={false}>No</Radio>
       </Radio.Group>
     </Form.Item>
  </Form.Item>
   </Form>
 </Col>
 </>
 )}
 const ComponentDemo = App;
 
 
 createRoot(mountNode).render(<ComponentDemo />);
```